# Material and textbooks for CLIL learners

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, english-language-learners

I have a quite broad questions. I'm a math teacher in Switzerland (high school level, school year 9-12). We teach following topics (among others): quadratic equations, quadratic functions, system of linear equations, exponential funcion and logarithm, combinatorics, probability theory, calculus.

We start to teach certain courses in English (but our studends are German speaking), therefore I'm looking for suitable textbooks, exercises material, suitable magazines (or links to such material) for CLIL (Content and Language Integrated Learning) learners in English.

I already purchased Hease's Mathematics for the international student (HL core) which is quite good and I'm looking for similar material.

Any help and good hints are appreciated.